# Rails form not passing image with carrierwave

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, forms, carrierwave

I've currently got an upload form that takes an epub file, parses it using epubinfo and then displays in another form to validate the information we're extracting is correct. We then submit this new upload from this form.

This first form (upload.html.erb) seems to work exactly as I'd expect, extracting all the information I required, including the cover image and displays it appropriately in the edit/verification form (new.html.erb). However, the issue lies in this second form (new). Upon posting it doesn't retain the cover image that was displayed, instead not saving anything, even though any other changed (or unchanged) data in this form posts just as it should.

To note, when the upload form posts, public/tmp gets two files, the epub and the png, and upon posting the new form, the epub tmp goes away and gets put into public, however the png stays in public/tmp.

Ruby 2.1.1p76
Rails 4.1
CarrierWave 0.10.0

/views/pages/upload.html.erb

```
      <%= form_for Book.new, :url => new_book_path do |f| %>
    <div class="form-group">
      <%= f.label :book, "Upload an epub" %>
      <%= f.file_field :book, class: "form-control" %>
      <%= f.hidden_field :book_cache %>
    </div>

    <br />

    <div class="form-group">
      <%= f.button "Upload", class: "btn btn-primary", data: {disable_with: "Uploading..."} %>
    </div>
  <% end %>
```

/app/controllers/books_controller.rb (somewhat sanitized):

```
class BooksController < ApplicationController
  before_action :redirect_to_book, only: [:index]
  before_action :set_book, only: [:show, :edit, :update, :destroy, :download]
  before_action :is_mod, only: [:edit, :update, :destroy]

    def create
    @books = Book.new(book_params)
    if @books.author.nil? && book_params[:author_name].present?
      @books.author = Author.where(name: book_params[:author_name]).first_or_create
    end
    if @books.series.nil? && book_params[:series_name].present?
      @books.series = Series.where(name: book_params[:series_name]).first_or_create
    end
    if book_params[:is_public].present?
    else
      @books.is_public == true
    end
    if @books.save
      redirect_to book_path(@books), success: "The book was successfully saved!"
    else
      redirect_to new_book_path
    end
  end

  def new
    @authors = Author.all
    @series = Series.all
    @books = Book.new(book_params)
    @books.extract_epub_info
  end

  private
    def set_book
      @books = Book.find(params[:id])
    rescue ActiveRecord::RecordNotFound
      redirect_to "/404"
    end

    def redirect_to_book
      redirect_to book_path(params[:book_id]) if params[:book_id]
    end

    def book_params
      params.require(:book).permit(:book, :cover, :title, :isbn, :summary, :is_public, :series_nbr, :author_id, :author_name, :series_id, :series_name, :tag_list, :book_cache)
    end

    def is_mod
      unless current_mod
        redirect_to book_path, error: "You're not allowed to edit books."
      end
    end

end
```

/app/uploaders/book_uploader.rb

```
class BookUploader < CarrierWave::Uploader::Base
  storage :file

  def store_dir
    "uploads/#{mounted_as}"
  end

  def filename
    "#{model.id}.epub"
  end

end
```

/app/uploaders/cover_uploader.rb

```
class CoverUploader < CarrierWave::Uploader::Base
  storage :file

  def store_dir
    "uploads/#{mounted_as}"
  end

  def filename
    "#{model.id}.png"
  end

end
```

/app/models/book.rb

```
class Book < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :author
  belongs_to :series
  has_many :downloads
  has_many :flags
  has_many :ratings
  has_many :raters, :through => :ratings, :source => :users

  validates :title, :author_id, presence: true

  attr_accessor :author_name, :series_name

  acts_as_taggable
  scope :public_books, ->{ where(is_public: true) }
  mount_uploader :book, BookUploader
  # validates_presence_of :book
  mount_uploader :cover, CoverUploader
  # validates_presence_of :cover

    searchable do
      text :title
      text :summary
      text :isbn
    integer :is_public
    end

  def epub
    @epub ||= EPUBInfo.get(book.file.path)
  end

  def extract_epub_info

    if epub.creators.first.name.include? ","
      self.author = Author.where(name: epub.creators.first.name).first_or_create
    else
      parts = epub.creators.first.name.split
      first = parts.first
      last = parts[1..-1].join(" ")

      self.author = Author.where(name: "#{last}, #{first}").first_or_create
    end

    self.title = epub.titles.first
    self.summary = epub.description
    self.is_public = true
    self.isbn = epub.identifiers.find{ |i| i.scheme == "ISBN" }.try(:identifier)

    if epub.cover.present?
      self.cover = epub.cover.tempfile
    else
    end
  end

end
```

And the edit form that displays the cover appropriately but doesn't post when you submit the form.
/views/books/new.html.erb:

```
<%= form_for @books, url: books_path, html: {multipart: true} do |f| %>
  <% if @books.errors.any? %>
    <div id="error_explanation">
      <h2><%= pluralize(@books.errors.count, "error") %> prohibited this author from being saved:</h2>
      <ul>
        <% @books.errors.full_messages.each do |msg| %>
          <li><%= msg %></li>
        <% end %>
      </ul>
    </div>
  <% end %>

  <br/><br/>

  <div class="alert alert-warning">
    <strong>Please validate that all of this information is correct before saving the book!</strong>
  </div>

  <br/>

  <% if @books.cover.present? %>
    <div align="center">
      <%= image_tag @books.cover %>
    </div>
  <% end %>

  <div class="form-group">
    <%= f.label :title %>
    <%= f.text_field :title, class: "form-control" %>
  </div>

  <div class="form-group">
    <%= f.label :author %>
    <%= f.collection_select(:author_id, @authors.order("name ASC"), :id, :name, {:include_blank => true} ) %>
    OR New Author Name:
    <%= f.text_field :author_name, class: "form-control" %>
  </div>

  <div class="form-group">
    <%= f.label :isbn %>
    <%= f.text_field :isbn, class: "form-control" %>
  </div>

  <div class="form-group">
    <%= f.label :summary %>
    <%= f.text_area :summary, class: "form-control", size: "20x10" %>
  </div>

  <div class="form-group">
    <%= f.label :series_nbr %>
    <%= f.text_field :series_nbr, class: "form-control" %>
  </div>

  <div class="form-group">
    <%= f.label :series %>
    <%= f.collection_select(:series_id, @series.order("name ASC"), :id, :name, {:include_blank => true} ) %>
    OR New Series Name:
    <%= f.text_field :series_name, class: "form-control" %>
  </div>

  <div class="form-group">
    <%= f.label :tag_list %>
    <%= f.text_field :tag_list, class: "form-control" %>
  </div>

  <%= f.hidden_field :book_cache %>

  <div class="form-group">
    <%= f.label :cover, "Upload a cover" %>
    <%= f.file_field :cover, class: "form-control" %>
  </div>

  <br/>

  <div class="form-group">
    <%= f.hidden_field :is_public, :value => "1" %>
    <%= f.submit class: "btn btn-primary", data: { confirm: "Are you sure all of this information is correct?\rYou will not be able to edit it later." } %>
  </div>

<% end %>
```

**EDIT for routes 11/2 @ 9:20ET**

routes.rb

```
App::Application.routes.draw do
  root "pages#home"

  # All pages
  get "browse" => "books"
  get "browse/new" => "books#newest"
  get "browse/popular" => "books#popular"
  get "browse/random" => "books#random"
  get "faq" => "pages#faq"
  get "empowerment" => "pages#empowerment"
  get "legal" => "pages#legal"
  get "pages/catalog"
  get "search" => "search#search"
  get "search/search"
  get "upload" => "pages#upload"
  get "download" => "pages#download"
  get "dmca" => "pages#dmca"

  # Catalog Routes
  get "catalog" => "catalog#index", defaults: {format: :atom}
  get "catalog/search" => "catalog#search", defaults: {format: :atom}
  %w{ newest popular random author title serie tag }.each do |section|
    get "catalog/#{section}", controller: :catalog, action: section, defaults: {format: :atom}
  end
  get "catalog/author/:id" => "catalog#authored_by", defaults: {format: :atom}
  get "catalog/tag/:tag" => "catalog#tagged", defaults: {format: :atom}

  # Normal Model stuff
  resources :authors
  resources :series
  resources :books do
    collection do
      get "tagged/:tag", action: :tagged, as: :tagged
      post "new", action: :new, as: :new_book
    end
    member do
      get :download
    end
  end
  resources :tags

  # Stuff for Mods and management
  devise_for :mods
  namespace "admin" do
    resources :mods
  end
  devise_scope :mod do
    get "mods" => "devise/sessions#new"
  end

  # Lists for dropdowns
  get "authorlist" => "books#authorlist"
  get "serieslist" => "books#serieslist"
  get "taglist" => "books#taglist"

  # Let's be nice and support old urls.
  get "book/show/id/:id" => "books#show"
  get "serie/:id" => "series#show"
  get "author/:id" => "authors#show"
  get "browse/author/:id" => "authors#show"

end
```

I'm not sure what else would be needed. I feel that what I'm missing is simple, but after staring at it for so long I've just stopped making any progress. I know that the cover image shows up in new.html.erb because it displays in the image_tag in the form, however upon post it doesn't save the param.

Halp! :(

Comment: Is the books/new form the one that isn't working properly?

Comment: Correct. Upload form works fine, but the new form doesn't save the cover image to the database.

Answer (score 0):

/views/pages/upload.html.erb -- missing `multipart: true`

`<%= form_for Book.new, html: { multipart: true } do |f| %>`

I don't think you need to supply the `url` argument unless you've set up your routes/models incorrectly. You should change this in your other forms as well.

/app/controllers/books_controller.rb

You're completely missing edit/update methods. Is this by design? Why? Is this why you're supplying the `url` option in the forms? This promotes confusion.

Have you viewed the contents of `book_params` to see if the image data is being received correctly? What about checking to see if the actual image files have been created? If they are created, perhaps they're just not accessible (check file permissions).

FURTHER EDIT: I can't determine how things are routed based on what you've shown. Please show your routes as well, and clearly describe which actions result in the unwanted consequences.

i.e., "I want to create a new book, but the uploaded image isn't saved" (meaning it doesn't exist in the database and there's no actual image anywhere on the disk).

or

"I can create a book and save the image, but upon viewing the EDIT page, the image doesn't show up"

Comment: Added the multipart: true to the new form (doesn't seem to make a difference, and shouldn't be required since form_for does it for you, however it's added to be consistent).

I don't usually use url's in the forms, these two forms are required as we need **anyone** to be able to upload a book and then interact with the validation form (new.html.erb), however they can't edit/destroy them after the fact.

OP was updated to include routes.

The image actually gets saved in /public/tmp as well as the book. Upon posting of new, the book goes away and saves, the cover does not. Remains in tmp.